# Writing logs from rsyslog to a mounted DFS folder

Tags: directory, permissions, shared, ubuntu-20.04, rsyslog

I have a rsyslog server on Ubuntu 20.04 for two routers. I want rsyslog to write all the logs to a shared folder from my domain so some users could access the logs anytime.
The problem is that syslog doesn't have the rights to write in the folder  (the rights: rwxr-xr-x).
 
I've tried changing the rights with *chmod 777 /Share1* and changing the owner of the folder with chown -- nothing happened. 
***Error during config processing: Could not open dynamic file '/Share1/log/127.0.0.1/Ubuntu.log' [state -3000] - discarding message [v8.2001.0 try https://www/rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]***
***Error during config processing: omfile: creating parent directories for file '/Share1/log/127.0.0.1/Ubuntu.log' failed: Permission denied [v8.2001.0 try https://www/rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]***

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    chgrp syslog /your/share_dir/
    chmod g+w /your/share_dir/
```